# Elementary proof of compact space = exhaustible space?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, topology

The work of Martín Escardó has demonstrated close parallels between classical topology o one hand and computability on the other hand.  (See for example "[Infinite sets that admit fast exhaustive search](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~mhe/papers/exhaustive.pdf)" *22nd Annual IEEE Symposium on Logic in Computer Science* (2007)  443–452)
Escardó identifies continuous functions with computable functions, and open sets with recursively enumerable sets.

Another identification is between the *exhaustible* sets on one hand and *compact* sets on the other.  A set $S$ is exhausible if, given a total predicate $P:S\to\mathbf{Bool}$, one can always decide whether $P$ holds for every element of $S$.  According to Escardó, there is a close relationship between exhaustible and compact sets.  For example:

- Finite sets are both compact and also obviously exhaustible.
- The natural numbers are not compact and are not exhaustible. (If they were, we could solve the halting problem.)
- But the one-point compactification of the naturals *is* exhaustible.
- The Cantor set of all sequences of booleans, that is all functions $f:\Bbb N\to\mathbf{Bool}$ is both compact and exhaustible.

I have found the discussion of compactness in Escardó's papers very hard to follow, with many forward references.  The nearest thing to a proof that I can identify is in section 8 of his notes on "[synthetic topology of data types](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~mhe/papers/barbados.pdf)". The proof in chapter 8 is very advanced.  In these notes compactness is initially *defined* to be exhaustibility, which doesn't make it easier to follow what is going on.

My question is:

> I keep hoping for an elementary proof, one which relates the conventional definition of compactness, in terms of open covers, to exhaustibility. I have not been able to find one myself and I have not been able to extract one from Escardó's papers.  Is there such a proof?

Comment: Perhaps this question would be better-suited to [cstheory.SE]?

Comment: That, or even [math.SE]. You are welcome to wait a few days and see if you can get an answer here; in fact, immediate cross-posting is discouraged on the network.

Comment: I have [reposted this on math.se](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1117032/elementary-proof-of-compact-space-exhaustible-space).

Comment: There is now [an answer on math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4596231/25554).